# Why do I need to use Activator CreateInstance?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I don't need to use create new instance via Activator createInstance so why do I need it? In which situations would I need to use Activator.CreateInstance()?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace App.CreateInstance
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            new MyCustomerManager().Save <MyCustomer>(new object[] {
                     1, 
                    "xxx", 
                    "yyyy" });
            }
    }

    public class MyCustomerManager
    {
        public void Save<TModel>(object[] Vals)
        {
            Type calcType = typeof(TModel);
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(calcType);
            PropertyInfo[] ColumnNames = instance.GetType()
                                                 .GetProperties();

            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.Length; i++)
            {
                calcType.GetProperty(ColumnNames[i].Name,
                                       BindingFlags.Instance 
                                     | BindingFlags.Public    )
                .SetValue(instance, Vals[i], null);
            }

            string result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.Length; i++)
            {
                result += String.Format("{0}:{1}", 
                    ColumnNames[i].Name, c
                    alcType.GetProperty(ColumnNames[i].Name,
                                          BindingFlags.Instance 
                                        | BindingFlags.Public   )
                           .GetValue(instance, null).ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    // Model
    public class MyCustomer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can do that without Activator.CreateInstance:

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace App.ReflectionToGeneric4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object[] Vals = new object[] { 1, "xxx","yyyy" };
            new MyCustomerManager().Save<MyCustomer>(Vals);
        }
    }

    // Model
    public class MyCustomer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyCustomerManager
    {
        public void Save<TModel>(object[] Vals) 
                                where TModel : class, new()
        {
            var instance = new TModel();
            Type calcType = instance.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] ColumnNames = calcType.GetProperties();

            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.Length; i++)
            {
                  calcType.GetProperty(ColumnNames[i].Name,
                                          BindingFlags.Instance
                                        | BindingFlags.Public    )
                          .SetValue(instance, Vals[i], null);
            }
            string result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.Length; i++)
            {
                result += String.Format("{0}:{1}", 
                    ColumnNames[i].Name, 
                    calcType.GetProperty(ColumnNames[i].Name, 
                                          BindingFlags.Instance 
                                        | BindingFlags.Public)
                            .GetValue(instance, null).ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scenarios:

- you aren't using generics, but just `Type`-based code
- you are using generic, but the constructor takes parameters - `new()` is limited to parameterless constructors
- there is a parameterless constructor, but it is not accessible (IIRC Activator will use private constructors if you ask)

But yes, in your case the `new()` constraint is ideal.

Comment: @Marck: +1  for the explanation

Comment: i need deeper explanations :(

Comment: @programmerist - What don't you understand?  Marc listed the situations in which you have to use Activator.CreateInstance, which was what you asked.  In most other cases, it is better to call a constructor directly, like in your second code with the `new()` constraint.

Comment: Perhaps a "deeper" question might solicit the response you require?

Comment: @programmerist happy to add more, but you'll need to tell me where you are unclear. But as an example, in protobuf-net I don't know the types at compile time, and it uses `Type` based code as the primary API; so it ***can't*** use `new()` - it has to use `Activator` instead.

Comment: Activator using new() ? is it true?

Comment: @programerist - IIRC the `new()` usage in generics uses the generic form of `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` - but as an implementation detail.